# JS - Передача функции в Web Worker

Tags: javascript, webworkers

Всем привет.
Предположим есть файл - **script1.js** и другие файлы **script1.js**.., у которых есть некоторые экспортируемые функции со своим контекстом. Есть так же файл **main.js**, из которого создаётся воркер.

Если создать воркер и передать через postMessage функцию (хоть в свойстве объекта, хоть без), то будет ошибка о невозможности клонировать с указанием функции.

*script1.js*

```
export function foo() {
  return 0;
}
```

*main.js*

```
import { foo } from './script1';

let worker = new Worker('script1.js');
worker.postMessage(foo);
// Error cloned
```

Необходимо передать функцию с контекстом в Worker. Есть ли такая возможность и как?

Comment: эээээм, зачем функцию передавать? оО

Comment: При передаче данные сериализируются, нельзя будет передать функцию. Какая у вас задача в общем?

Comment: @ThisMan, мне нужно вынести в Worker некоторые тяжелые функции. Они взаимодействуют с Backbone моделью.

Comment: @ThisMan, нужно передать экземпляр класса с его методами, выполнить что-то внутри скрипта и вернуть результат работы.

Comment: @J.Defenses, это так не работает, функции должны быть уже внутри воркера

Comment: А какая цель? можно запускать новые воркеры передавать туда функцию через конструктор объекта воркер, запускать воркер, по выполнении задачи - отправлять сообщение основному потоку и уничтожать воркер.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно выполнить функцию в `WebWorker` без вынесения функции в отдельный js файл, и допустимо каждый раз запускать новый `WebWorker`, можно сделать это вот так:

```js
function workerTask() {
   return Math.random() * Math.random()
}

runInWebWorker(workerTask, console.log);

function runInWebWorker(task, callback) {
  task = `${task};(function(){this.postMessage(${task.name}())})();`;
  var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([task]))); 
  worker.onmessage = e => worker.terminate() || callback(e.data);
}
```

Comment: Пытаюсь передать класс в worker для того, чтобы код сохранял "модульность". Import в файле воркера не проходит - сам воркер не модуль. Если использовать ваш метод, то по сути я создаю файл на лету? Тогда в него же надо и всю остальную логику вставлять? Создание экземпляра класса и исполнение методов для получение результата, а потом и отсылать результат? А как тогда мне вставить в тест создаваемого файла текст, описывающий класс в отдельном файле?))

Comment: @Leonid да, надо собрать строку и передать

Comment: `let worker = new Worker('./worker_module.js', {type: 'module'});` Оказывается можно воркер использовать в качестве модуля! И все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

При передаче данные сериализуются, в следствии чего нельзя передать функцию. Функции, которые должны выполнится внутри воркера должны быть внутри воркера.